# How to convert DTED Level 1 into SRTM DTED

Tags: srtm, dted

We have a GIS tool that handles only SRTM DTED level 1 terrain files. SRTM level 1 terrain files are limited to 60 deg lat. So I need to fill up the gap from 60 lat up to 90 deg lat. 
I have DTED level 1 data covering the area 60 deg lat and upwards that could be used for that.
Is there a way to convert that DTED level 1 data into SRTM data?
Very much appreciated,

Yvan

Comment: Not sure but try global mapper.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know that SRTM was natively in a different format. The elevation data I work with is from the shuttle missions, but it's all in DTED format. See if you can find a different source for your data.